# How to access the service from different jar from parent project

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have following architecture of my project:
There are two libs (imported as jar in POM.xml):

- Component 1
- Component 2

These libs are imported in the parent project to expose the public APIs.
**Now the scenario is Component 2 also depends upon some of the services from Component 1.** (e.g. **Component 2** may call **Service A or Serive B** from **Component 1**).

**How can I make those services accessible to Component 2?** I'm using Java & Spring.

`

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                         Component Imported as jars                  |
|                                    +------------------------------+ |
|                                    |  Component 1                 | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |  |Service A                | | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |  |Service B                | | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    +------------------------------+ |
|  Parent Project                                                     |
|                                                                     |
|                                    +------------------------------+ |
|                                    |  Component 2                 | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |  |Service 1                | | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |  |Service 2                | | |
|                                    |  +-------------------------+ | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    |                              | |
|                                    +------------------------------+ |
|                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you make changes to Component 2/Component 1? i.e. do you own codebase?

Comment: You usually define spring beans using one of approaches, e.g. annotations, XML configuration, etc. In there you define relationships between beans and in runtime you have all dependencies injected properly.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko yes I own all of them.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project that contains only the interfaces for service 1, 2, A and B,  then
import in Component1 and Component2 poms then
modify services to implements their respective interfaces
remember add @Service annotation  in the implementations

```
@Service
public class ServiceA implements ServiceAInterface
```

and if you need use serviceA in component 2
add attribute with the interface as type and @Autowired annotation

```
@Autowired
private ServiceAInterface service;
```

in this way you can use serviceA functionality without move code